# Unknwon Member Bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, color) in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-bitmap

I'm developing a Xamarin application with Native Shared project.
 This is my Inversion filter method for bitmaps

```
using System;
using Android.Graphics;

public static Bitmap Inversion (Bitmap bmp) {

        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                var pixel = new Color(bmp.GetPixel(x, y));
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Rgb(255 - pixel.R, 255 - pixel.G, 255 - pixel.B));
            }
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

I'm getting a Java.Lang.IllegalStateException error, when applying filter to a bitmap and I have no idea how to fix it, here is the place it occurs:
[image]

I get that this is some Xamarin error not recognizing .SetPixel() method, by I don't know why this is occuring. 
Here is the content of pixel variable:
[image]

Please help

Comment: Post the actual code in text, not screen caps

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about adding it. I updated my question

Comment: .SetPixels() doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Bitmap` is immutable and thus you are getting the `IllegalStateException`, you can make a copy of it and then use `SetPixel` on the copy.

```
public static Bitmap Inversion(Bitmap bmp)
{
    var mutableBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, bmp.GetConfig());
    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        {
            var pixel = new Color(bmp.GetPixel(x, y));
            var color = Color.Rgb(255 - pixel.R, 255 - pixel.G, 255 - pixel.B);
            mutableBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, color);
        }
    }
    return mutableBitmap;
}
```

Comment: @AleksanderLipka No problem, within the *IllegalStateException* stack trace you will see that `SetPixel` is failing due to the fact it is an Virtual (or Abstract) method, personally a misleading error, but there are immutable/mutable Bitmaps and thus it makes sense **if** you look at the ASOP Java source as an immutable Bitmap does not have that method implemented